# question about self the map $f_a$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let us denote by $\mathbb{D}$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}$. For $a\in\mathbb{D}$, consider map $f$ defined as $f_a(z)= \frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z}$ for $z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$. Then it maps unit circle onto itself in a one-one manner. So any point $e^{it}$ is mapped onto some other point $e^{is}$.
Then will the point $e^{-it}$ be mapped to $e^{-is}$ under this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be rephrased: for $|z| = 1$, is it true that $$ f_a(\overline{z}) = \overline{f_a(z)} ?$$

The answer is negative, consider:

$$ f_{a}(e^{-i\theta}) = {a - e^{-i\theta} \over 1 - \bar{a} e^{-i\theta}} \neq {\bar{a} - e^{-i\theta} \over 1 - a e^{-i\theta} } = \overline{f_a(e^{i\theta})}.$$  Equality would only hold if $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For a neat geometric description of why this last statement must hold check out T. Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis".

Comment: Thanks alot for the reference!!!